# Integral of $\frac{1}{100-x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't understand how the integral below:

\begin{align}
\int{\frac{1}{100-x}dx} = \ -\log|x-100| +c
\end{align}

When I integrate I get the answer:
\begin{align}
\ -\log|100-x| +c
\end{align}

I understand that it probably has something to do with the absolute value function, would someone kindly explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: $|a|=|-a|$; $x-100=-(100-x)$.

Comment: You are not "using $|x-100|$ instead of $|100-x|$". These two expressions are the same !

Answer (score 2):

The absolute value function disregards sign, so |4| = |-4| for example.

That also means that $|x-100| = |100-x|$.

Comment: In the context of a differential equation,  where x is the population of function x(t), t is time, and x(0) = 200. Is there any specific reason why I would have to use |x-100| instead of |100-x|?

Comment: if you know that x>100, then use |x-100|

Comment: In fact, if you know $x \gt 100$, you can use $(x-100)$ without absolute value signs, making your integral $-(x-100)+c = 100-x+c$, noting that your integrand is negative

Comment: Thanks so much for the help so far. If the differential equation for this logistic population growth was 1000(dx/dt) = x(100-x), what would suggest that x has to be greater than 100?

Comment: thank you for providing the equation

Comment: this basically means that the population peaks at 100

Comment: so that means that you would want to use |100-x|

Comment: the 1000 represents the growth factor (very slow)

Comment: the x means that the more animals there are the faster they can reproduce with each other and grow

Comment: 100-x means as they approach carrying capacity growth slows down

Comment: and obviously when x=100 at max capacity, no more growth

Answer (score 2):

Since the argument of the logarithm is in absolute value signs, it doesn't really matter the order in a case like this. As we can see,

$$|a-b| = |(-1)(b-a)| = |-1||b-a| = |b-a|$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right|=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left|x_i\right|$$This property, which basically says that *absolute value of product is same as the product of individual absolute values*, implies that $\left|100-x\right|$ can be rewritten as $\left|-1\right|\cdot\left|x-100\right|$ which equals $\left|x-100\right|$.